# Auto starting Python with sudo access

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, sudo

I would like to know the simplest way to set-up a python app I made to launch automatically on my ubuntu-server os, and I'd like it to be able to run commands with Popen() while having sudo access. What would be my best option, and how would I execute implementing it?

Comment: Do you have a reason for any part of your script to _not_ be running as root? If you start out in a privileged account, then you don't need to use `sudo` to gain privileges later. Also, you can _drop_ privileges using other tools that don't require config files &c to be set up just so as sudo does, so it's easier and often saner to start as root and drop to an unprivileged user for things that don't need root, instead of starting as an unprivileged user and jumping up to root for things that _do_ need root.

Comment: (In general, `sudo` is not ideal to use in scripts; better to stick to using it only interactively, and use other methods for programmatic privilege escalation so your software isn't dependent on having specific values configured in software that's typically focused on defining what human administrators are and aren't allowed to do)

Comment: (Similarly, you can start your main process as root, spawn an unprivileged subprocess, do anything that doesn't need root in the subprocess, and ask the main process to do anything that _does_ need root).

Comment: Wow, you seem way more knowledgeable and experienced than I currently am. Thank you for your time, I'll do my best not to waste it. It's an account creation app that acts as a webpage and also runs commands to create users and give them proper permissions. Originally it was just run as root, but our old service died and I'm figuring out how to remake it correctly. The webpage (flask) doesn't need to be run as root, but the commands it runs do need root. I was primarily trying to limit access as much as possible, but all I need is for the app to start automatically and have access with sudo.

Comment: Not having full root privilege is me trying to limit access on a public facing service in a department filled with people more than happy to test my security.

Comment: Gotcha. Yeah, you definitely don't want a web UI running as root. OTOH, you can have your web UI put requests on a queue, and something with more privileges process the queue (after validating the queue's contents carefully). Lots of tools available for running message queues -- in descending order of my personal preference, a few available options I've personally worked with include NATS, redis, or RabbitMQ.

Comment: Cool, what would you use to start a python app automatically on startup as simply as possible. This will be something maintained by other people after I make it so I'd like to keep it simple.